# I need muenchain Grouping code for the below xml input

Tags: xml, xslt

i had copied my input xml below and also my desired out put xml too. Can you please help me in getting my output using Meunchain Grouping.

It has to be grouped by RebateInvoiceID first and then RebateEventID has shown in desired output below.

**Input XML**

```xml
<EnterpriseDocument InterfaceName="RebateInvoiceAdjustmentImport" ClientID="1000001" ClientName="XXXX" Version="1.0" CreationSource="File" CreationTimestamp="2012-05-11T09:53:16" xmlns:script="script">
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001878" RebateEventID="1003042" BusinessUnitCode="0402" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="89"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001878" RebateEventID="1003042" BusinessUnitCode="0405" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="94.42"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001878" RebateEventID="1003043" BusinessUnitCode="0406" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="147.5"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001878" RebateEventID="1003048" BusinessUnitCode="0423" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="97.36"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001879" RebateEventID="1008042" BusinessUnitCode="0433" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="89"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001879" RebateEventID="1008042" BusinessUnitCode="0434" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="70.24"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001879" RebateEventID="1008942" BusinessUnitCode="0435" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="53.08"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001879" RebateEventID="1008942" BusinessUnitCode="0435" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="59.4"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001978" RebateEventID="2003042" BusinessUnitCode="0437" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="127.85"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001978" RebateEventID="2003042" BusinessUnitCode="0438" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="180.04"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001978" RebateEventID="3003042" BusinessUnitCode="0446" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="146.61"/>
  <RawXMLRow RebateInvoiceID="1001978" RebateEventID="3003042" BusinessUnitCode="0448" CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="76.56"/>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

**Desired output XML**

```
<EnterpriseDocument InterfaceName="RebateInvoiceAdjustmentImport" ClientID="1000001" ClientName="XXXX" Version="1.0" CreationSource="File" CreationTimestamp="2012-05-10T16:09:07" xmlns:script="script">
  <RebateInvoice RebateInvoiceID="1001878">
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="1003042">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0402">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="89"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0405">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="94.42"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="1003043">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0406">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="147.5"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="1003048">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0423">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="97.36"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
  </RebateInvoice>
  <RebateInvoice RebateInvoiceID="1001879">
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="1008042">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0433">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="89"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0434">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="70.24"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="1008942">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0435">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="53.08"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
  </RebateInvoice>
  <RebateInvoice RebateInvoiceID="1001978">
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="2003042">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0437">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="127.85"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0438">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="180.04"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="3003042">
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0446">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="146.61"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
      <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="0448">
        <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="1000057" PaymentAmount="76.56"/>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </RebateProgram>
  </RebateInvoice>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

---

Thanks for the reply. But i still getting an error saying my stylesheet is empty or XML is not formatted correctly. Let me explain you everthing in detail. I have a .js file when i double click .js file it will take the .csv in that folder and uses the xslt and gives me an .xml output file.

```
 /* code for my .js file */ (Please copy this to note pad and save it as             
 InvoiceAdjustment.js) 

showAbsolutePath("InvoiceAdjustment.js");

   function showAbsolutePath(path)
   {
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var s = "";
  s += fso.GetAbsolutePathName(path);

 var foldername = s.substring(0,s.indexOf(path,0));
 showFolderFileList(foldername);
  }

function showFolderFileList(foldername)
{
 var fso, f, fc, filename;

fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.GetFolder(foldername);
fc = new Enumerator(f.files);

for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext())
{
  filename = "";
  filename += fc.item();

  if (filename.slice(-4) == ".csv")
  {
    convertCSVtoXML(foldername, filename);
  }
 }  

 fso = null;
}

function  convertCSVtoXML(foldername, filename)
{ 
 var objDOMDocument = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0"); 
  objDOMDocument.async = false; 

//Create Header
 objDOMDocument.appendChild(XMLHeader(objDOMDocument)); 
 var objXMLDOMNode = objDOMDocument.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Document"); 

 // Declare XML object -- this makes it easier to pass as a parameter 
 var objXML  = new Object(); 

 // Open the extracted csv from zip file
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

 var csvFilename = filename;

  var tso = fso.OpenTextFile(csvFilename, 1); 
  var strInput; 

 // Loop through the file 
 while(!tso.AtEndOfStream)  
 { 
  strInput = tso.ReadLine();

  var vInputLine = strInput.split(","); 
  objXML.a = vInputLine[0];
  objXML.b = vInputLine[1];
  objXML.c = vInputLine[2];
  objXML.d = vInputLine[3];
  objXML.e = vInputLine[4];



  if (objXML.a != 'RebateInvoiceID')
 {
 objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(XMLFileNode(objDOMDocument,objXML));
 }    
 } 
tso.Close();

 // Load Transform file
var TransformXSL = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
TransformXSL.async = false  
TransformXSL.load(foldername + "\\InvAdj.xsl");

// Load XML file and transform it
var TempStagingDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
TempStagingDoc.async = false; 
TempStagingDoc.loadXML(objDOMDocument.xml);      
var FinalStr = TempStagingDoc.transformNode(TransformXSL);

// Grab just the file name minus any extension
var fn = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf(".csv")); 
tmpxml = fn + ".xml";  

// Write out the transformed file. If writing out just the xml file before transform  
//  FSObject.WriteLine(objDOMDocument.xml);     

var FSObject = fso.CreateTextFile(tmpxml, true);
FSObject.WriteLine(FinalStr);
FSObject.Close();




// Clear all objects
objDOMDocument = null; 
fso = null;
TransformXSL = null;
objXML = null;
TempStagingDoc = null;
 }

function XMLHeader(objDOMDocument)
{ 
 var XMLHead;
XMLHead = objDOMDocument.createNode(1, "Document",""); 

var objXMLDOMAttribute = objDOMDocument.createAttribute("Version"); 
objXMLDOMAttribute.text = "1.0";
XMLHead.attributes.setNamedItem(objXMLDOMAttribute);

var objXMLDOMAttribute = objDOMDocument.createAttribute("CreationTimestamp"); 
objXMLDOMAttribute.text = getTimestamp();
XMLHead.attributes.setNamedItem(objXMLDOMAttribute);

return(XMLHead);
} 

function XMLFileNode(objDOMDocument,objXML)
{     
var objXMLDOMNode = objDOMDocument.createNode(1, "RawXMLRow","");

objXMLDOMElement = objDOMDocument.createElement("RebateInvoiceID"); 
objXMLDOMElement.text = objXML.a;
objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(objXMLDOMElement);

objXMLDOMElement = objDOMDocument.createElement("RebateEventID"); 
objXMLDOMElement.text = objXML.b;
objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(objXMLDOMElement);

objXMLDOMElement = objDOMDocument.createElement("BusinessUnitCode");
 function getBusinessUnitCode(){
  var r = String(objXML.c).length;
  if(r == 4)
return String(objXML.c);
if( r == 3)
  return "0"+String(objXML.c);
  if(r == 2){
          return "00"+String(objXML.c);
  }
  else
          return "000"+String(objXML.c);

}
objXMLDOMElement.text = getBusinessUnitCode();
 objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(objXMLDOMElement);

objXMLDOMElement = objDOMDocument.createElement("CategoryID"); 
objXMLDOMElement.text = objXML.d;
objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(objXMLDOMElement);

objXMLDOMElement = objDOMDocument.createElement("PaymentAmount"); 
objXMLDOMElement.text = objXML.e;
objXMLDOMNode.appendChild(objXMLDOMElement);

return(objXMLDOMNode);
}

function getTimestamp()
{
var d = new Date();
var mm = padZeros(d.getMonth()+1);
var dd = padZeros(d.getDate());
var hh = padZeros(d.getHours());
var mn = padZeros(d.getMinutes());
var ss = padZeros(d.getSeconds());

return d.getFullYear()+"-"+ mm +"-"+ dd +"T"+ hh +":"+ mm +":"+ ss;
}

function padZeros(s)
{
if (s < 10)
{
s = "0" + s;
}
return(s);
}

function getDate(stringDate)
{
var a = String(stringDate).split( "/" );
var strXML ;

 strDate = "" ;

 for ( var i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++ )
 {
 if (a[i].length == 1)
     strDate += "0" + a[i];
  else
     strDate += a[i];
  }

 strDate += "" ;

 return strDate;
}

  /* code for xslt */ ( make an xslt using below code and save it as InvAdj.xsl)

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:script="script" exclude-result-  
 prefixes="msxsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- ROOT -->
<xsl:template match="/">
<EnterpriseDocument>
  <xsl:attribute name="InterfaceName">RebateInvoiceAdjustmentImport</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="ClientID">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="normalize-space(ClientID)">
        <xsl:value-of select="//Document/RawXMLRow/ClientID"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>1000001</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="ClientName">XXXX</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="CreationSource">File</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="CreationTimestamp">
    <xsl:value-of select="script:getTimestamp()"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:call-template name="InvAdjData"/>
  </EnterpriseDocument>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="InvAdjData">
  <xsl:for-each select="//Document/RawXMLRow[not(RebateInvoiceID=preceding-
   sibling::RawXMLRow/RebateInvoiceID)]">
    <xsl:sort select="RebateInvoiceID"/>
    <RebateInvoice>
      <xsl:attribute name="RebateInvoiceID">
        <xsl:value-of select="RebateInvoiceID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:variable name="InvoiceID">
        <xsl:value-of select="RebateInvoiceID"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Document/RawXMLRow[not(RebateEventID=preceding-
      sibling::RawXMLRow[RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID]/RebateEventID)]">
        <xsl:if test="RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID">
          <xsl:variable name="EventID">
            <xsl:value-of select="RebateEventID"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <RebateProgram>
            <xsl:attribute name="RebateEventID">
              <xsl:value-of select="RebateEventID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Document/RawXMLRow[not(BusinessUnitCode=preceding-
     sibling::RawXMLRow[RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID and  
     RebateEventID=$EventID]/BusinessUnitCode)]">
              <xsl:if test="RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID and RebateEventID=$EventID">
                <xsl:variable name="BUCode">
                  <xsl:value-of select="BusinessUnitCode" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <BusinessUnit>
                  <xsl:attribute name="BusinessUnitCode">
                  <xsl:value-of select="BusinessUnitCode"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                  <xsl:for-each select="//Document/RawXMLRow[not(CategoryID=preceding-
    sibling::RawXMLRow[RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID and RebateEventID=$EventID and 
    BusinessUnitCode=$BUCode]/CategoryID)]">
                    <xsl:if test="RebateInvoiceID=$InvoiceID and RebateEventID=$EventID 
    and BusinessUnitCode=$BUCode">
                      <ItemCategoryPayment>

                        <xsl:attribute name="CategoryID">
                          <xsl:value-of select="CategoryID"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="PaymentAmount">
                          <xsl:value-of select="PaymentAmount"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                      </ItemCategoryPayment>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </BusinessUnit >
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>

          </RebateProgram >
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </RebateInvoice >
     </xsl:for-each>

     </xsl:template>

     <!-- BEGIN JSCRIPT HELPER CODE, KEEP THIS SECTION AS SMALL AS POSSIBLE IT'S A 
     PERFORMANCE HOG -->
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="script">
     <![CDATA[

   function getTimestamp()
   {
    var d = new Date();
    var m, dy, hr, mn, se;

   if (d.getMonth()+1 < 10)
   {
    m = "0"+(d.getMonth()+1);
       }
   else if (d.getMonth()+1 > 9)
   {
   m = d.getMonth()+1;
     }

   if (d.getDate() < 10)
     {
      dy = "0"+(d.getDate());
     }
   else if (d.getDate() > 9)
   {
   dy = d.getDate();
    }

    if (d.getHours() < 10)
   {
   hr = "0"+(d.getHours());
   }
  else if (d.getHours() > 9)
   {
   hr = d.getHours();
   }

  if (d.getMinutes() < 10)
  {
  mn = "0"+(d.getMinutes());
  }
  else if (d.getMinutes() > 9)
   {
    mn = d.getMinutes();
    }

   if (d.getSeconds() < 10)
    {
     se = "0"+(d.getSeconds());
    }
  else if (d.getSeconds() > 9)
    {
     se = d.getSeconds();
    }

   return d.getFullYear()+"-"+ m +"-"+ dy +"T"+ hr +":"+ mn +":"+ se;
    }

   ]]>
   </msxsl:script>

  Now copy this records into an excel sheet and save it as .csv 

  RebateInvoiceID   RebateEventID   BusinessUnitCode    CategoryID  PaymentAmount
  1001878   1003042 402 1000057 89
  1001878   1003042 405 1000057 94.42
  1001878   1003043 406 1000057 147.5
  1001878   1003048 423 1000057 97.36
  1001879   1008042 433 1000057 89
  1001879   1008042 434 1000057 70.24
  1001879   1008942 435 1000057 53.08
  1001978   2003042 437 1000057 127.85
  1001978   2003042 438 1000057 180.04
  1001978   3003042 446 1000057 146.61
  1001978   3003042 448 1000057 76.56
```

Now place the .csv input file and .js file and xslt in to one folder and double click the .js file it will generate an .xml file.

now i need the same result using muenchain grouping method in xslt code. Can you help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: It's Muenchian - this might help you search for tutorials

Comment: Are you sure you need Muenchian grouping? The task may be achieved using `<xsl:sort>` and predicates. And there're two nodes in the input xml with different `@PaymentAmount` — it's not clear how the only one should be selected while processing the input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stylesheet sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="RawXMLRow" use="@RebateInvoiceID"/>
  <xsl:key name="k2" match="RawXMLRow" use="concat(@RebateInvoiceID, '|', @RebateEventID)"/>

  <xsl:template match="EnterpriseDocument">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="RawXMLRow[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @RebateInvoiceID)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RawXMLRow">
    <RebateInvoice RebateInvoiceID="{@RebateInvoiceID}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @RebateInvoiceID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', concat(@RebateInvoiceID, '|', @RebateEventID))[1])]" mode="evt"/>
    </RebateInvoice>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RawXMLRow" mode="evt">
    <RebateProgram RebateEventID="{@RebateEventID}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k2', concat(@RebateInvoiceID, '|', @RebateEventID))" mode="bus"/>
    </RebateProgram>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RawXMLRow" mode="bus">
    <BusinessUnit BusinessUnitCode="{@BusinessUnitCode}">
      <ItemCategoryPayment CategoryID="{@CategoryID}" PaymentAmount="{@CategoryID}"/>
    </BusinessUnit>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the answer but i still getting an error. I had explained everything again. Can you please have a look at it.